# Mapear json utilizando jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

estou com uma dúvida em como mapear um json para um model, realmente não faço ideia para que lado ir, vi algum material na internet, mas oq me falta mesmo é entender realmente como isso funciona ali na parte do jackson. meu código segue abaixo, quem puder ajudar.

ZenviaRequest

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ZenviaRequest {

@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("from")
private String from;
@JsonProperty("to")
private String to;
@JsonProperty("msg")
private String msg;
@JsonProperty("schedule")
private String schedule;
@JsonProperty("callbackOption")
private String callbackOption;
@JsonProperty("aggregateId")
private String aggregateId;
@JsonProperty("flashSms")
private boolean flashSms;

//todos os getters and setters
}
```

ZenviaResponse

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ZenviaResponse {

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    private String statusCode;
    @JsonProperty("statusDescription")
    private String statusDescription;
    @JsonProperty("detailCode")
    private String detailCode;
    @JsonProperty("detailDescription")
    private String detailDescription;
    @JsonProperty("mobileOperatorName")
    private String mobileOperatorName;
    @JsonProperty("received")
    private String received;

    //todos os getters and setters
    }
```

Minha chamada

```
public void senderMulti(List<ZenviaRequest> zenvia) {

   //pego a lista que recebi e faço aqui toda lógica para gerar uma String Full

    Response response = null;
    try {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Entity payload = Entity.json(full); // <-----

        response = client.target("https://api-rest.zenvia360.com.br/services/send-sms-multiple")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .header("Authorization", "Basic ***************")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .post(payload);

        System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
        System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));

        // aqui meu codigo desanda, não sei oque fazer aqui
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInString = response.readEntity(String.class);

        List<ZenviaResponse> objList = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, new TypeReference<List<ZenviaResponse>>(){});

        response.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

O retorno do Json

```
status: 200
headers: {Server=[Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)], Connection=[close], Date=[Tue, 17 Apr 2018 00:01:51 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json]}
body:{
  "sendSmsMultiResponse" : {
"sendSmsResponseList" : [ {
  "statusCode" : "10",
  "statusDescription" : "Error",
  "detailCode" : "080",
  "detailDescription" : "Message with same ID already sent"
}, {
  "statusCode" : "10",
  "statusDescription" : "Error",
  "detailCode" : "080",
  "detailDescription" : "Message with same ID already sent"
}, {
  "statusCode" : "10",
  "statusDescription" : "Error",
  "detailCode" : "080",
  "detailDescription" : "Message with same ID already sent"
} ]
  }
}
```

ele vem todo lindo ai, mas como consumir ele para um List de ZenviaResponse, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço bastante.

tentando com esse código agora eu recebo esse erro abaixo.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity input stream has already been closed.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.ensureNotClosed(EntityInputStream.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:832)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:785)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:108)
    at br.com.trendplataform.rotas.ZenviaSender.senderMulti(ZenviaSender.java:122)
    at testando.main(testando.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `readEntity(Class<T> entityType)` só pode ser utilizado uma única vez por resposta, já que quando é executado, o *input stream* é consumido e a conexão é fechada (caso a resposta seja lida como um *input stream*, ele deverá ser fechado para que a conexão também seja).

No seu código, ele está sendo evocado duas vez nos seguintes trechos:

```
System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));
```

E:

```
String jsonInString = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Para evitar que a exceção ocorra, inverta a ordem das linhas acima e passe a variável `jsonInString` como argumento para o método `println`:

```
String jsonInString = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("body: " + jsonInString);
```

Quanto ao uso mapeamento, você precisa fazer com que sua classe corresponda ao formato do JSON. Então você deveria ter as seguintes classes:

SendSmsMultiResponse:

```
public class SendSmsMultiResponse {

    @JsonProperty("sendSmsMultiResponse")
    private SendSmsMultiResponseList sendSmsMultiResponse;

    //getters e setters
}
```

SendSmsMultiResponseList:

```
public class SendSmsMultiResponseList {

    @JsonProperty("sendSmsResponseList")
    private List<SendSmsResponse> sendSmsResponseList;

    //getters e setters
}
```

SendSmsResponse:

```
public class SendSmsResponse {

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    private String statusCode;
    @JsonProperty("statusDescription")
    private String statusDescription;
    @JsonProperty("detailCode")
    private String detailCode;
    @JsonProperty("detailDescription")
    private String detailDescription;

    //getters e setters
}
```

E, para desserializar o JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SendSmsMultiResponse sendSmsMultiResponse = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, SendSmsMultiResponse.class);
```

**Obs**: o Jackson pode ser integrado ao Jersey utilizando a dependência `jersey-media-json-jackson` (que deve estar na mesma versão do Jersey utilizada), nenhuma configuração adicional é necessária. Caso você a adicione, você poderia ler a entidade diretamente da resposta dessa forma:

```
response.readEntity(SendSmsMultiResponse.class);
```